# Executing GUI .sh file with Osx

Tags: terminal, console, sh

I'm a very beginner in this kind of stuff so I suppose the solution for this problem may not be so difficult. 
I'm trying to open the GUI file of MEKA (an extension to weka) and it's manual tells me to execute a file called: `run.sh`.
I go to the console and type '*my file's location*'/run.sh and what happens is I get the message: "The main class could not be located and loaded", or something like that.

This is the content of the `run.sh`file:

```
#!/bin/bash

MEMORY=512m
MAIN=meka.gui.explorer.Explorer

java -Xmx$MEMORY -cp "./lib/*" $MAIN $1
```

**So any tips?**

Thank you.

Comment: There is a # before the exclamation point in: "!/bin/bash" that for some reason didn't appear in the question.

Comment: It was formatted as Markdown, fixing it.

Comment: Your bash script is executing correctly (as in it's being read and all its command executed), its the java command which is emitting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The script depends on it being run from the folder it resides in. Try:

```
cd fileLocation
./run.sh
```